# Como dividir elementos de um array usando o laço For?

Tags: c#

**Resumo do Programa**

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora que pede ao usuário a quantidade de números que serão calculados,  a operação e os números em questão. Para guardar os valores, utilizo um *array*. O código que calcula os números do *array* é:

**O Código**

`for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { result /= num[i]; }`

Onde arrayLength é o tamanho do *array*, e "result" é uma variável do tipo *double* declarada com o valor 0.

**Problema**

*Supondo que tenhamos um *array* unidimensional com 2 posições cujos valores sejam num[0] = 120 e num[1] = 5*

O problema é que quando a divisão é executada, o que acaba sendo calculado é: (0 / 120) / 5

**Conclusão**

Gostaria de saber como percorrer pelo meu *array* "num" e dividir os valores contidos nele de um modo eficiente. E se possível uma maneira de reduzir o tamanho código.

**Código Completo**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int arrayLength, loopCounter = 0;
        int numCounter = 1;
        int i = 0;

        double result = 0;
        string operation = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Digite a quantidade de números a serem calculados");

        arrayLength = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\nEscolha a operação:\n\n1: Soma\n2: Subtração\n3: Multiplicação\n4: Divisão (Temp. Desativado)\n");
        operation = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("");

        double[] num = new double[arrayLength];

        while (loopCounter < arrayLength)
        {
            Console.Write("Digite o {0}º valor: ", numCounter);
            num[loopCounter] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            numCounter++;
            loopCounter++;

        }

        switch (operation.ToUpper())
        {
            case "1":
                for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
                {
                    result += num[i];
                }
            break;

            case "2":
                for ( i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
                {
                    result -= num[i];
                }
            break;

            case "3":
            result = 1;
                for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
                {
                    result *= num[i];
                }
            break;

            case "4":
                for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
                {
                    result /= num[i];
                }
            break;

            default:
            Console.WriteLine("Operação Inválida.");
            break;
        }

        Console.Write("\nO resultado é: ");

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(result,2));
    }
```

Comment: O mesmo problema acontece para a multiplicação, que não pode começar em 0. Melhor seria meter o `result` como o primeiro elemento do array e fazer os cálculos dai para a frente. Nota: atenção à gralha de escrita do Length `arrayLenght` que é bastante comum, apesar de não afetar o programa em si.

Comment: @Isac Obrigado pela correção gramatical. Poderia corrigir meu código-fonte para melhor visualização?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode iniciar o result com a primeira posição do array, e o loop começar a partir da segunda, apenas uma sugestão:

```
 case "4":
 {
     result = num[0];
     for (i = 1; i < arrayLength; i++)
         result /= num[i];
 }
 break;
```

Comment: Acredito que esta deva ser a resposta. Porém a unica coisa que eu faria é simplificar o código, fazendo um loop direto ai invés de varios loops dentro de cada switch.

Comment: Olá, editei meu código e agora ele está funcionando, Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Seu código tem uma caracterísca muito comum em código acadêmicos. São pensados de forma a processar estados matematicos. Tente enxergar como é que você, como humano, faria esse cálculo, e depois rescreva.

Exemplo: **Calcule a soma dos 3 números: 1, 2 e 3**. Vc não começa assim:

> Zero + 1 = 1, 1 + 2 = 3, 3 + 3 = 6

Vc simplesmente faz:

> 1 + 2 = 3, 3 + 3 = 6

Agora, passe a maneira que você realiza o calculo para códigos:

```
result = num[0]; // começa já no primeiro número.
for (int i = 1; i < num.Length; i++)
     result += num[i];
```